# 2checkout sandbox not sending INS notifications

Tags: integration-testing, payment-gateway, 2checkout

I am trying to test INS in my sandbox account using [this link](https://sandbox.2checkout.com/sandbox/notifications/ins_test)

But it is not working. My Nitifications url is : http://localhost:61700/Orders/TestNotifications

(this url is my local machine url. because website not hosted in server now).

1. Why INS notifications are not sending to this URL?
2. How can I test INS service in 2checkout sandbox account without hosting website in server?

Answer (score 1):

1. You are trying to send INS to your local machine which is not possible unless you specify your public ip in the url. Because 2checkout can not find your localhost.

http://public.ip.here:61700/Orders/TestNotifications

2. You can use online mock server like https://webhook.site to just test the notification data. Otherwise, you have to host your application.